# Unable to close pop-up window on makemytrip.com

Tags: selenium-webdriver, popup

```
public class makeMyTrip {
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\jarFiles\\geckodriver-v0.14.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/");

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='holidays-international']")).click();
String MainWindow=driver.getWindowHandle();

for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
}

driver.close();
// Switching to Parent window i.e Main Window.
driver.switchTo().window(MainWindow);

//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@placeholder='Type Departure City']")).sendKeys("New Delhi");
}
}
```

Thanks,

Sarita

Comment: What exception or error you are getting? Could you share the stack trace?

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `frame` in between. You need to switch to that `frame`.
Please see the workable code.

```
    driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='holidays-international']")).click();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
    Thread.sleep(7000L);
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@name='notification-frame-22a34493b']")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[@id='webklipper-publisher-widget-container-notification-close-div']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000L);
```

Hope this solves your issue.